# How to define ReactJS IState interface when data comes from .js file function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have the following interface in a React component using typescript

```
interface IState {
  moviesList: {
    [x: string]: any;
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    genre: { [x: string]: any; _id: string; name: string };
    numberInStock: number;
    dailyRentalRate: number;
    publishDate?: string;
  };
}

class Movies extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = {
    moviesList: fakeMovie.getMovies()
  };
```

The fakeMovieService.js has the following array of objects:

```
const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",
    title: "Airplane",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181b",
    title: "Wedding Crashers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181e",
    title: "Gone Girl",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 4.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181f",
    title: "The Sixth Sense",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 4,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471821",
    title: "The Avengers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  }
];
```

and the function:

```
export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}
```

I'm new to typescript and I've been trying to set the IState interface as above but keep getting an error "non assignable type" upon calling public state .... in class.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error and the line, it looks like it should work. I wouldn't use `[x: string]: any;` if you don't need to add keys to the objects but that's just a bets practice

Comment: (22,5): Type '({ [x: string]: any; _id: string; title: string; genre: { [x: string]: any; _id: string; name: string; }; numberInStock: number; dailyRentalRate: number; publishDate: string; } | { [x: string]: any; _id: string; title: string; genre: { ...; }; numberInStock: number; dailyRentalRate: number; publishDate?: undefined; ...' is not assignable to type '{ _id: string; title: string; genre: { [x: string]: any; _id: string; name: string; }; numberInStock: number; dailyRentalRate: number; publishDate: string; }'.

Comment: Property '_id' is missing in type '({ [x: string]: any; _id: string; title: string; genre: { [x: string]: any; _id: string; name: string; }; numberInStock: number; dailyRentalRate: number; publishDate: string; } | { [x: string]: any; _id: string; title: string; genre: { ...; }; numberInStock: number; dailyRentalRate: number; publishDate?: undefined; ...'.

Comment: in line 22 "class Movies extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = {
    moviesList: fakeMovie.getMovies()
  };"

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to define the interface as Array of Objects

```
interface IState {
  movies: Array<{
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    genre: any;
    numberInStock: number;
    dailyRentalRate: number;
    publishDate?: string;
  }>;
}
```